# Does the module of 2 meshing spur gears have to be the exact same value ?

Tags: gears

Does the module of 2 meshing spur gears have to be the exact same value ? What is the allowable difference?

So basically my module is off by 0 01 and my coworker made a model and it works. So I'm just wondering what the allowable difference  is ?

Ps these are custom made gears.

Comment: It depends what you mean by "it works". Since the modules are different, the teeth will be in sliding contact not rolling contact. The rotation speed of the  two shafts might not be in a constant ratio. The effect of those things on gears with light loads and slow speeds, or a high power high speed gearbox, will be very different. Personally I would just fix the design.